# Preloader with css and jquery loader after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, onload, preloader

hi am tying to make a preloader for my site with css and jQuery. here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KWh5d/2/).It is working perfectly. But the problem is i need this to work before page load. now preloader is working after the page is loaded.

```
$('.la-anim-1').addClass('la-animate');
```

just need to run the script before page load.help..

cheers thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are applying your CSS won't work in this scenario. You need keyframes animation. The idea is to start the animation on the element as soon as it is rendered, and then when the page load is complete, stop it by removing the class (and better still removing the element itself).

***Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/KWh5d/6/***

Start the element with the class applied:

```
<div class="la-anim-1 la-animate"></div>
```

Add this to your CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes preloader {
  0%   { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
  100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0); }
}
@keyframes preloader {
  0%   { opacity: 0; transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0); }
  100% { opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(0%, 0, 0); }
}
```

And then add this animation to your `.la-anim-1.la-animate` class:

```
.la-anim-1.la-animate {
    -webkit-animation: preloader 5s infinite;
    animation: preloader 5s infinite;
}
```

And then, your jQuery inside DOM ready:

```
$('.la-anim-1').removeClass('la-animate');
```

And better still, remove the element itself:

```
$('.la-anim-1').remove();
```

**Edit**: Added standard along with -webkit- vendor prefix. Please add other vendor prefixes as needed.

Comment: Updated the answer with standard version along with -webkit- vendor prefix.

Answer (score 1):

Keep your code under document load function.

```
$(document).load(function(){
  $('.la-anim-1').addClass('la-animate');
});
```

Comment: thank you for answer. but i did the same. it make the preloader load after the page load.

Answer (score 0):

**With Bootstrap, Jquery, CSS**

```
<style>
 .overlay {
    position: absolute; background-color: white; top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto; z-index: 10;
}
    .overlay div{ position: relative; z-index: 10; top:30%; left: 50%;}
</style>
```

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div class="overlay">
    <div class="spinner-border text-secondary" >
        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
    </div>
</div>

<div> Helloo World</div>
</body>
```

**JQuery**

```
<script>
$(window).on('load', function(){
    $( ".overlay" ).fadeOut(100, function() {
        $( ".overlay" ).remove();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.